# How can i save multiple items to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

So i have an ecommerce app which which for a product, i want customers to post different variants of the product with the quantity and price for the variant. Then on save, I want the product to be save based on the number of variants.

For instance if there are 3 variants of the product, the product should be saved 3 times with same name and description, but each save would have a single variant.

Here's what i have done.

```
       const [values, setValues] = useState([])

       function addItem(e) {
           e.preventDefault()
           setValues([...values, { quantity, weight, price }])
           setQuantity('')
           setWeight('')
           setPrice('')
       }

        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Product Name*'
          value={productName}
          onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
        />
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          type='number'
          placeholder='Quantity'
          value={quantity}
          name={quantity}
          onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='number'
          placeholder='Weight (kg)'
          value={weight}
          name={weight}
          onChange={(e) => setWeight(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type='number'
          placeholder='Price'
          value={price}
          name={price}
          onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
```

OnClick, the item is added to a state. Then onSubmit, i try to loop through the state

```
 for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  const res = await createProduct({
    productName,
    price: price[i],
    quantity: quantity[i],
    weight: weight[i],
  })

  console.log(res)
}
```

It doesn't work

Here's the express controller

```
exports.createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newProduct = await Product.create(req.body)
    res.json(newProduct)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Express` function handling the data insertion?

Comment: I have added it